# In VB6, is it possible to call a function with an operator in the parameter?

Tags: vb6, parameters

I'm having a really hard time finding an answer for this, with such generic terminology, and it's possible my question is still difficult to parse.  I have some code with a variable representing the amount of free disk space remaining as a percentage.  I want to call it into a function, where I use the reverse amount in a message to the user, i.e. the amount of used space.  Can I do a little math in the function call?

```
Public Sub MyApp()
    Dim nFreeSpace As Integer
    nFreeSpace = GetFreeSpace
    DisplayUsedSpace 100 - nFreeSpace 'Is this valid?
End Sub
Private Function DisplayUsedSpace(ByVal nUsedSpace As Integer) As Boolean
    MsgBox("You have used " & nUsedSpace & "% of your disk drive space.")
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, you can pass expressions as parameters.  More puzzling is why DisaplyUsedSpace is a Function, since you are not returning a result.

Comment: Oh, that's just a really stripped down version of the function.  It does all kinds of stuff besides this little snippet.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but I think more puzzling is why you didn't just run it and find out if it is valid. It probably took you longer to type this question.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could've at that.  It was in a big app that I would've needed to take a few steps to compile and copy to a server to run correctly, but I suppose I could've written a small test app to try.  On balance though, this was more convenient, since I could work on other stuff in the meantime.  And now there's a definite answer for others to find if they ever need to. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is valid. Although, I probably would write it as this

```
Call DisplayUsedSpace(100 - nFreeSpace)
```

But, your code would work fine too.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can - VB will calc the expression first.

You could also reverse it before the call

```
Public Sub MyApp()
    Dim nUsedSpace As Integer
    nUsedSpace = 100 - GetFreeSpace
    DisplayUsedSpace nUsedSpace
End Sub
```

If you want it really compact:

```
Public Sub MyApp()
    Call DisplayUsedSpace(100 - GetFreeSpace)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, I mainly was interested in using fewer variables.  I originally had it do the calculation in the DisplayUsedSpace function.